# Creating Azure Function Key using ARM template fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I cannot figure out how to create azure function key for my function using ARM

I am creating a child resource inside the function itself, so this resource block lives within the main resource block of the function.

```
 "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/keys",
          "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
          "name": "slapifd-dev",
          "properties": {
            "value": "xxxxxxx"
          }
        }
      ]
```

but I get this error message

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'slapifd-dev' for type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/keys' at line '1' and column '1633' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: As already stated, the function app needs to be created first. You could then create another host key.

Answer (score 0):

The 'name' property should be set with the nested resource names too, according to the resource type hierarchy.
In your scenario, the 'name' property should be {site name}/{function name}/{key name}. For example: slapifd-dev/MyFunction/MyKey

Comment: but I have not deployed any functions yet I want to create a host key valid for all functions

Comment: this is not possible, the key is scoped by a function which should exist first

Comment: No I created a host key which can be done without a function so that solved the issue